# sh script list folders only in directory

Tags: shell, sh

Can someone please help me out with the following code. I'm updating a legacy sh script and i'm tying to build a dynamic list of configurations a user can select.

The code i'm using is

```
#!/bin/sh

PS3="Select the folder from the list(quit to exit):"
options=($(ls /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/))
select name in "${options[@]}" "quit"
   do
      if [$name=="quit"]; then
          exit;
      fi
      echo "Selected $name"
   done
```

The code above gives me a list of all folders located in the profiles folder. The next step is to filter this list for folders starting with "Int" so I've been trying

```
options=($(ls /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/Int*))
```

But that gives me a bunch of folders which are located a level or two below the profiles folder.

Can someone please help me out and take a look at my code, I'd like to just have a list of just folder names (no path) that first 3 letters are "Int" located in etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles

Comment: This doesn't look like sh, arrays are an extension which only modern shells support

Comment: Use `ls -d` to stop `ls` from descending into subdirectories.

Comment: Hi AlexP, thanks that works, the -d results in just the folders i want but the result of the ls displays the full path of the listed folders and not just the actual (short) folder name. Do you have any idea what I can try just to list the short folder names and not the full path?